# My Site Issue in SharePoint 2013 "internet explorer cannot display the webpage"

Tags: sharepoint-enterprise, sharepoint-designer, sharepoint-foundation, mysite

I configured my site in SharePoint 2013,when i am clicking "AboutMe"in the top ribbon it was opening the page   "internet explorer cannot display the webpage" but for a site administrator i can able to create my site.I am thinking my be its permission's issue can you please any one help on this.

Answer (score 0):

Check the link and also check the site self creation permission on the web application. If you have MySites, make sure it is set up correctly.

Comment: In checked in Self Service Site Creation at web application level it is fine only.Set up is correct.Can any one please let me know the issue

Comment: Compare the link that is showing the blank page with the link that you are getting as an admin.